# Create Custom Post Type from front end template using Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want a form on the front end for creating a Custom Post Type using the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com) plugin.

I'm using code from the tutorial [Create A Front End Form](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/create-a-front-end-form/) combined with code I found on Stack Overflow that defines the `$options` for `<?php acf_form(); ?>`.

The code I have so far is:

```
<?php acf_form_head(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php /* The loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            $options = array(
                'post_id' => $post->ID, // post id to get field groups from and save data to
                'field_groups' => array(), // this will find the field groups for this post (post ID's of the acf post objects)
                'form' => true, // set this to false to prevent the <form> tag from being created
                'form_attributes' => array( // attributes will be added to the form element
                    'id' => 'post',
                    'class' => '',
                    'action' => 'submit',
                    'method' => 'post',
                ),
                'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() ), // return url
                'html_before_fields' => '', // html inside form before fields
                'html_after_fields' => '', // html inside form after fields
                'submit_value' => 'Submit', // value for submit field
                'updated_message' => 'Post updated.', // default updated message. Can be false to show no message 
            );
            acf_form( $options );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm not sure how to make this work:

- How do I specify the post ID?
- How/where do I specify the connection to the Custom Post Type and the custom fields I want to show?

Can you please tell me where in the code can I get specific information like my field IDs, etc?

Comment: Why you have ​​the statement made ​​a comment. ? `);` in this line `'updated_message' => 'Post updated.', // default .... to show no message );` your `<?php $options = array(` The array is not terminated properly.

Comment: caused it by mistake when copying to stackoverflow screen. (fixed)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried like (set `88` to your field group ID)

```
<?php $options = array(
'post_id' => $id,
'field_groups'  => array(88 ), // this is the ID of the field group
 ....
```

maybe this can help

[How to edit a user profile on the front end](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/9786)
[Front end post editing using a form](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106561)
[acf-edit-title-content](https://bitbucket.org/jupitercow/acf-edit-title-content)